# Why does var a = ...arguments fail, if console.log(...arguments) is OK?

Tags: javascript, operators, spread-syntax

Code A, this is OK and logs `[ 1, 2, 3 ]`

```
function fn() {
    console.log(...arguments);
}

fn([1, 2, 3]);
```

Code B, this fails with `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...`
Also, wrapping `...arguments` in `()` won't help either.

```
function fn() {
    var a = ...arguments;
}

fn([1, 2, 3]);
```

In both cases, I assume, we have a `RHS` lookup. Why is it OK to pass on `...arguments` to `console.log` (or other function), but not to assign it to a variable?

*PS. I know that this would never stand in real life code or there are other, better solutions to this. My question is purely theoretical/conceptual and limited to understanding why the different behavior occurs.*

Comment: Can't you just assign it to `a` without `...`? `var a = arguments[0]; //Your array`.

Comment: @Arg0n Sure, as I noted, this is not an actual problem in real life software. I was just startled why ```...arguments``` is passed to ```console.log``` as an array (without the need to wrap it in ```[ ]```), when the assignment needs explicit ```[ ]``` to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two applications of the spread syntax are:

1. turn items of an iterable value into arguments of a function call
2. turn items of an iterable into elements of an Array

So this works:

```
function fn() {
    var a = [...arguments];
}
```

Comment: @DrunkenMaster Try calling it like this: `fn(1, 2, 3);` which is how restful parameters work. You only supply one parameter (an array). You could also do this: `fn([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]); //a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`.

Comment: really this should be using a spread parameter tho. `function fn(...a) { ... }` achieves the exact same thing as your function but without the nasty `arguments` magic

Comment: I think it's very misleading to call this syntax an operator. Even the question is based on this misunderstanding, thinking of it as an operator that has a return value. It is officially called the _spread syntax_.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work as in CODE B... Invalid syntax

You can spread in fn params like

```
function fn(...params) 
{
  ...
}
```

or  `Array` and `Object`

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5],
b = [6,...a];

var x = {a:1,b:1},
y = {c:1,...x}
```